# How do I access a property attribute of a Django model through a QuerySet filter in Django Views?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have a model:

```
class IpdReport(models.Model):
    patient=models.ForeignKey(Patient, on_delete=CASCADE)
    package=models.ForeignKey(Package, on_delete=CASCADE)
```

The `Patient` model looks like this:

```
class Patient(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    mr_uid=models.CharField(max_length=9) #A gender field needs to be added here later

    @property
    def patient_number(self):
        if self.pk:
            return "{}{:04d}".format('PN/D/', self.pk)
        else:
            return ""

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name+"-"+self.patient_number
```

Now, I want to filter data of `IpdReport` to in a `views` function to display a table based on the `property` attribute of the `Patient` model, that is, `patient_number`.

Here's what I tried but it didn't work:

```
def sort_by_pt(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        pn=request.POST.get('enter_patient_number')
        report=IpdReport.objects.filter(patient__patient_number=pn)
        total1=report.aggregate(Sum('realization__amount_received'))
        total2=report.aggregate(Sum('realization__deficit_or_surplus_amount'))
        context={'report': report, 'total1':total1, 'total2':total2}
        return render(request, 'account/ipdreport.html', context)
    else:
        sort=EnterPatientNumber()
        return render(request, 'account/sort.html', {'sort':sort})
```

The error it threw: **Related Field got invalid lookup: patient_number**

What are my options to achieve it?

Comment: Just extract the `pk` from the posted data and filter with that... You _can't_ refer properties in a query, you can bring their logic into the query though.

Comment: Isn't there any way to achieve what I want to though? Like, at all?

Comment: Your property is simply of the form `PN/D/{pk}`. Why complicate things and write some complex query? Simply extract the `pk` from the string (not difficult) and filter for it...

Comment: See, the thing is, the hospital has four branches in four different cities, the D in PN/D/{pk} is the initial of one of those cities. For another city it will be PN/S/{pk} and so on. Looking at it, branch-wise, your suggestion does work well but I'm going to fetch all the data from all the centers to make macro-level financial reports, that time I won't be able to differentiate between the patient numbers as to which belongs to which center, I need to be able to look up the patient number completely in order to fetch out the correct data. Even complicated solutions will work, if you have any!

Comment: If D is the _initial_ of one of the cities why are you hardcoding it? Store it as a field in your database! Don't maintain such data by having it differ in code everywhere. Again I stand by my previous statement, just parse the string you have, get the pk and filter for it.

Comment: If I store it in a field, would Django allow to create an auto-incrementing alphanumeric field? The reason I am after it is that I've been asked for that result. Is this possible?

Comment: Your pk is being auto-incremented is it not? Keep it that way. Just add a separate field that will store only the city (or initial of the city). No need to store two different things in _one_ column, since they are different they should be in separate columns.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your time and suggestions.